# Is $\mathcal{M}_n(R) $ a free $R$-module?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Is $\mathcal{M}_n(R) $ a free $R$-module?

I think any canonical map 
$$R^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_n(R)$$
would give us an $R$-module isomorphism. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is obviously a free module with basis consisting of the $n^2$ "unit" matrices.  (That is, the collection of matrices which are $1$ on precisely one position.)